# \max and superscript problems in equation

Tags: equations, subscripts

I need to display this equation:
[image]

But I keep getting the following:

[image]

I do not know how to make the subscript in the \max function and the superscript to end.
Here is my code:

```
\begin{equation*}

Q(s,a) \leftarrow Q(s,a)+\alpha \left( r+ \gamma \max_{{a^'}\in{A}} Q(s^',a^')-Q(s,a)\right)

\end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this much simpler code, and you'll have no problem. Note it's better to  control the size of the parentheses here  with the pair `\Bigl( … \Bigr)` rather than `\left( … \right)`.

```
\begin{equation*}
Q(s,a) \leftarrow Q(s,a)+\alpha \Bigl( r+ \gamma \max_{a' \in A } Q(s',a') - Q(s,a)\Bigr)
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! It works as well. Thanks.

Comment: Could you expand on why is it _better_ to use ``Bigl(`` instead of ``left(``?

Comment: @runr: Compare the oversized parentheses in the O.P. and the result with `\Bigl( … \Bigr)`.

Comment: Agree for the case of O.P., that's due to upperscript below the ``max``; these get smaller when using your code. However, with your code snippet, the ``\in`` symbol draws slightly lower than the bottom of the ``Bigl(`` parentheses. Now I don't know what are the typesetting rules (hence the question), but I could imagine why the larger ones from ``left(`` could make sense.

Answer (score 6):

The most important protip for using LaTeX:

> When your compiler shows you errors: **read the errors and try to resolve them**.

The reason that your code generated odd output is because LaTeX encountered an error in your code and did its best to guess what you meant. Frequently the guess is wrong, and so you get the wrong output.

Now, to the error: your compilation should've shown something like

```
l.5 ...w Q(s,a)+\alpha \left( r+ \gamma \max_{{a^'
                                                  }\in{A}} Q(s^',a^')-Q(s,a)\r...
```

this tells you that when LaTeX read up to the prime sign `'` it encountered an error. The error is because that the sign `'` is *already in superscript mode* when used in mathematics. If you try to put `^'` this is a double superscript and causes an error.

So all you need to do is to remove the doubling. Instead of `a^'`, type `a'` and this will give you the correct output.

Comment: Yes, I can now see all those extra superscripts, thanks for taking the time and explaining the error.

Answer (score 2):

Use `limits` to put some text or math below `\max`

Here is the code which you can try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*} 
Q(s,a) \leftarrow Q(s,a)+\alpha\,\left(r+ \gamma \max\limits_{a'\,\in\, A}\,Q(s',a')-Q(s,a)\right)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This one works even better, since I get the subscript right below the \max function. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Q(s,a) \leftarrow Q(s,a) + \alpha \Big ( r + \gamma \mathop{\text{max}}_{a' \in A} Q(s',a') - Q(s,a) \Big )
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. I see now that I had all those unnecessary superscripts.

Comment: Happy to help you :)  Please mark the problem as solved!